# In $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, $G\cong \mathbb{Z}^r$, does $f\cdot g\geq 0$ imply $f\geq0$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^r$ be a free abelian group, and $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ be the group ring of $G$. Define a partial ordering $\leq$ on $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ by

$$\sum_{g\in G}n_g[g]\leq\sum_{g\in G}n'_g[g]\iff n_g\leq n_g' \,\,\forall\, g,$$

and define

$$\mathrm{ord}\left(\sum_{g\in G}n_g[g]\right)=\sum_{g\in G}n_g.$$

> If $f,g\in \mathbb{Z}[G]$ are elements with $\mathrm{ord}(f),\mathrm{ord}(g)\geq1$, does $f\cdot g\geq 0$ imply $f\geq 0$ and $g\geq 0$?

The choice that $G$ be torsion free in this question is very important: Finite order points makes it extremely easy to generate counter examples. For example, if we choose $G=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ then we can let

$$f=[1]+[2]-[0], \,\, g=[1]+[2],$$

and compute $f\cdot g =2[0]\geq 0$. The condition $\mathrm{ord}(f),\mathrm{ord}(g)\geq 1$ is to stop trivial examples like $f=-[1]$, $g=-[1]$, $f\cdot g = [1]\geq 0$
.

Trying to work out examples by hand feels like I'm playing whack-a-mole: You can force some terms to be positive by hand, but then others become negative in the process. This statement is a technical lemma that I need for a longer proof to work out, and I've been stuck on it for weeks now.

Comment: This smells like a question about Fourier transforms and positive-definite functions, but I can't make the connection yet.

Comment: Take $G=\mathbb Z$ and let $x\in G$ be a generator. Then $x^4+4=x^4+4x^2+4-4x^2=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$. This seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: @VictorOstrik You are completely correct. Thank you so much for the counter example; That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @VictorOstrik is right, bur you can go further: It may happen that both $f$ and $g$ violate the "nonnegative coefficients" condition. Example: $f=x^4-x°3+x^2+x+1$, $g=x°4+x^3+x^2-x+1$.

Comment: @Ilya Bogdanov Thanks, this is great example!